# Why AngularJS sends X-XSRF-TOKEN header as JSON string?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, angular-cookies

[Angular sets the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header to the value of the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie:](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L663)

```
var xsrfValue = isSameDomain(config.url, $browser.url())
                ? $browser.cookies()[config.xsrfCookieName || defaults.xsrfCookieName]
                : undefined;
if (xsrfValue) {
  headers[(config.xsrfHeaderName || defaults.xsrfHeaderName)] = xsrfValue;
}
```

But, if one sets the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie using `$cookieStore` (for Rails integration, for example):

```
$cookieStore.put("XSRF-TOKEN", "my_token");
```

[the cookie is stored as JSON string:](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngCookies/cookies.js#L158)

```
put: function(key, value) {
  $cookies[key] = angular.toJson(value);
}
```

This means that the header will have the extra double quotes:

```
X-XSRF-TOKEN    "my_token"
```

Why Angular doesn't call [`fromJson()`](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/angular.fromJson) when it sets the value of the header so that the header will look like this:

```
X-XSRF-TOKEN    my_token
```

?

That would save us from removing the extra double quotes on the server side.

Am I missing something obvious here?

**Note:** I'm not looking for workarounds. I'm trying to understand whether this behavior is the intended behavior, and if yes, what is the rationale?

Comment: I don't know if it's the intended behavior, but it may have a very desirable side effect of preventing the XSRF token from being recognized when received as a cookie.  After all, CSRF works specifically because browsers send their cookies with all requests, so a token misplaced in a cookie that can't be properly read would help prevent accidental undermining of the protection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here is the official answer I got:](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2704#issuecomment-18138637)

> The real problem here is that you are trying to use the $cookieStore
>   for the wrong purpose. The $cookieStore is an abstraction on top of
>   $cookie, which works with objects and serializes them to JSON. If you
>   want to assign the XSRF token then just use $cookie to write it, which
>   works directly with strings.

In other words, one should do:

`$cookies["XSRF-TOKEN"] = "my_token"; // Stored as: my_token`

rather than:

`$cookieStore.put("XSRF-TOKEN", "my_token");   // Stored as: "my_token"`